# How to remove the <br> tag from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, line-breaks

I've an array titled `$error_msg` as follows:

```
Please select at least 1 question issue<br>This question has been already reported<br>
```

Now I'm converting this array into json format by using following code:

```
    $response_data = array();
    $response_data['que_issue_error'] = 'yes';
    $response_data['error_msg'] = $error_msg['error_msgs'];    
    $response_data = json_encode($error_msg);
    echo $response_data;
    die;
```

After echo the output is as follows:

```
{"que_issue_error":"yes","error_msg":"Please select at least 1 question issue<br>This question has been already reported<br>"}
```

Actually I want to make the 
 track workable but what's happening is the 
 tag is printing as it is. Can anyone help me how to correct this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `str_replace()`?

Comment: What do you mean at the end of your question?

Comment: If you print to the end user the `error_msg` key from the json object, they will see the new lines instead of the tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$data = // your data // $response_data
$data = str_replace("<br>", "", $data);
$data = str_replace("<br />", "", $data);
```

To remove all html tags, use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags):

```
$data = strip_tags($data);
```

You can also use regular expressions: use this regex to remove empty br

Try

```
$data = // your data
$pattern = "/<br[^>]*><\\/br[^>]*>/"; 
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);
```

To replace all empty html tags:

```
$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
$response_data['error_msg'] = preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "",  $error_msg['error_msgs']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Replace tag for blank space
$response_data['error_msg'] = preg_replace('/<.+>/', ' ',$error_msg['error_msgs']);
```

OR simple strip tags (for any html tags)

```
$response_data['error_msg'] = strip_tags($error_msg['error_msgs']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove all HTML tags, you can use the strip_tags function

```
$response_data['error_msg'] = strip_tags($error_msg['error_msgs']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you're trying to do but you can try this:

```
str_replace("<br>", "\n", $data); //That depends on where you are tring to display the output
```

It'll maybe solve your problem and maintain the break line, or if it's not work
you can just take the break line off like this:

```
str_replace("<br>", "", $data);
```

Hope it helps!